# Method Based Authorization at Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I have to  methods published as rest services. 
I want to apply basic authorization security on one method lest say "**gpnfeedback**".
I do not want to apply any authorization over **sendgpn**
 How I can configure SecurityConfig.java? I have used following configration but still having authorzation error when callling **http://localhost:7071/gpns/rest/sendgpn**

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/gpns/rest/")
public class GpnsRestController {

   @CrossOrigin
   @RequestMapping(value = "/sendgpn", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
   public @ResponseBody
   GpnsResponse sendgpn(@Valid @RequestPart(value = "data", required = true) SendGpnMessageMsisdnListReq sendGpnMessageMsisdnListReq, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "photo") MultipartFile photo, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "video") MultipartFile video,
         @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "videothumbnail") MultipartFile videothumbnail) {

   }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/gpnfeedback", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public @ResponseBody
   GpnsResponse gpnfeedback(HttpServletRequest http, @Valid @RequestBody GpnFeedbackReq gpnFeedbackReq) {
   }


}
```

**Security**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


  public static final String ROLE_CLIENT = "CLIENT_USER";

  @Autowired
  private DatabaseAuthenticationProvider databaseAuthenticationProvider;

  @Autowired
  private GpnBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint basicAuthenticationEntryPoint;

   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web.ignoring().antMatchers("/soap/lb/**");
   }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(this.basicAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


    // @formatter:off
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/gpns/rest/gpnfeedback/**").hasRole(ROLE_CLIENT)           
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

    // @formatter:on
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {

    //will be invoked in given order

    builder.authenticationProvider(this.databaseAuthenticationProvider);

  }

}
```

**UPDATE-1:**
I have changed the  rules with following one. Althout I can send **http://localhost:7071/gpns/rest/sendgpn** method without any authorization,  http://localhost:7071/gpns/rest/gpnfeedback is not hanled by  **databaseAuthenticationProvider**

```
http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/gpns/rest/gpnfeedback/**").hasRole(ROLE_CLIENT)  
      .antMatchers("/gpns/rest/sendgpn/**").permitAll()          
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is related to this line in your configuration:

```
.anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
```

Basically, what you're saying here is that every request (aside from the ignored on) **has to be authenticated** but you don't care about what roles it has. Try using this one instead:

```
.anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic()
```

Alternatively, if you wish only to permit **sendgpn**, you could use this:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/gpns/rest/gpnfeedback/**").hasRole(ROLE_CLIENT)  
      .antMatchers("/gpns/rest/sendgpn/**").permitAll()          
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
```

**EDIT**
As for your update, my guess is that you've somehow misconfigured the provided or you have incorrect data in your DB. For instance if ROLE_CLIENT has the value of "CLIENT" then Spring will expect the value in DB to be "ROLE_CLIENT" - it adds the "ROLE_" prefix to roles.

Comment: It works partially, I mean sendgpn is allowed but gpnfeddback is not handled by this.databaseAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: How can you tell? Could you update the question with your details since this is another issue altogether

Comment: As  you can see that I have only added .antMatchers("/gpns/rest/sendgpn/**").permitAll()    based on your suggest, it allows to invoke sendgpn method without authoization but why gpnfeedback method is not handled by databaseAuthenticationProvider?

Comment: But how do you know that it's not being handled by the provider?

Comment: If you have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/FingolfinTEK/a1ef87a55abe7c5f931507711e31142d) you'll see that the same configuration works perfectly fine. I think you have misconfigured your provider somehow

Comment: My guess is that your DB isn't populated correctly - like I said, the provided configuration will definitely call the provider that you have configured it to call, the easiest way to confirm it is to set a breakpoint in your code and see what happend and what exactly fails.

Comment: O I have found the problem, If Authorization header is not set in request ,databaseAuthenticationProvider is not triggered.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help :)